# Dnlib - Не заменяются строки констант

Tags: c#

В Исходном файле (который изменяем) есть такая строка:

```
public const string Test = "{ConstText}";
```

Её я пробую изменять этим методом, ищу строку и пробую её изменить.

```
var module = ModuleDefMD.Load(/* ... */);
foreach (var type in module.GetTypes().Where(t => t.HasMethods))
{
  foreach (var method in type.Methods.Where(m => m.HasBody))
  {
     IList<Instruction> instr = method.Body.Instructions;
     for (int i = 0; i < instr.Count; i++)
     {
       if (instr[i].OpCode == OpCodes.Ldstr) // string'овые опкоды
       {
           if (instr[i].Operand.ToString().Contains("{ConstText}")) // Что ищем и заменяем
           {
               instr[i].Operand = "NewText"; // На что заменяем
           }            
       }
        
     }
  }
}
```

Но оно не изменяется почему-то. Видимо из-за `const`, но если я уберу и сделаю так:

```
public static string Test = "{ConstText}";
```

То так изменяется.
Как изменить текст константы?

---

Смог найти константу через поиск по полям:

```
var list = new StringBuilder();
try
{
   using (var module = ModuleDefMD.Load(Resources.Stub))
   {
     foreach (var type in module.GetTypes().Where(t => t.HasMethods))
     {
       IList<FieldDef> fieldstr = type.Fields;
       for (int i = 0; i < fieldstr.Count; i++)
       {
         list.AppendLine($"FieldType: {fieldstr[i].FieldType}");
         list.AppendLine($"Name: {fieldstr[i].Name}");
         list.AppendLine($"FullName: {fieldstr[i].FullName}");
         list.AppendLine($"DeclaringType: {fieldstr[i].DeclaringType}");
         list.AppendLine($"GetType: {fieldstr[i].GetType()}");
         continue;
       }
    }
  }
 }
 catch { }
 File.WriteAllText("listCLI.txt", list.ToString());
```

`fieldstr[i].Name` - это наши константы.

Comment: Вероятно CLR не позволит это сделать стандартным путем через присваивание, потому что константа по своей природе неизменяемая. `Operand` в рантайме какого типа `System.String`? Новый текст длиннее или короче старого?

Comment: @aepot, странно, он не показывает какой тип, я попробовал искать но не находил. Ну это же как бы строка всё таки и тип же `string` должен быть. Текст не короче, но есть и длиннее

Comment: А если `Console.WriteLine(instr[i].Operand.GetType())`

Comment: Есть один способ изменить константу типа `string` через прямую запись в память, но есть ограничение - нельзя увеличить длину строки. Уменьшить можно. Если он вам подходит, я покажу. Но перед этим надо убедиться, что это 100% `System.String`.

Comment: @aepot, `nullReference` ошибку выдаёт что мол `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта`

Comment: А если убрать `const`, напишет `System.String`?

Comment: @aepot, да, если убрать - то да. Но мне нужно именно `const`

Comment: А может вам ее надо искать не в опкодах методов, а в полях? `Fields`.

Comment: @aepot, может быть, только я не шибко силён с этой библиотекой, но если вы поможете с этим, буду благодарен!

Comment: Я вообще никак не силен, но скорее всего это `type.Fields`, судя по тому, что я вижу в исходниках dnlib - `IList<FieldDef>`.

Comment: В `instr[i].GetOpCode()` выдаёт `nop`

Comment: nop - это опкод "ничего не делать"

Comment: при чем тут тело метода? вам ненужны методы, вообще, в классе есть поля и методы, вам нужны поля. Вместо `type.Methods` пройдитесь циклом по `type.Fields`. Вы же помните, как класс в C# выглядит? Вы видели когда-нибудь поля в методах? :) Я не видел.

Comment: @aepot, ))) да я тоже об этом подумал, изменил уже, нашёл константы, обновил вопрос

Comment: Остаётся понять, как заменить её)

Comment: Чтобы ее заменить, надо найти ее значение, нужный вам текст. В этом я вам не помощник.